# Index blank page delete _install folder

Tags: php, mysql, installation, configuration

I installed [pH7-Social-Dating-CMS](https://github.com/pH7Software/pH7-Social-Dating-CMS)), on paid hosting, after delete/rename `_install` folder, my website is blank, if rename again from `_installold` to `_install` I receive:

> Security Alert – pH7Builder
> Please remove "_install/" folder from your server before continuing.
> You can delete this folder using an FTP client (FileZilla or other) or
> through cPanel File Manager.

> You can also delete this folder with an SSH connection if your host
> allows. Below is the UNIX command for doing this: sudo rm -rf
> /YOUR-PUBLIC-SERVER-PATH/YOUR-WEBSITE/_install/ → Once done, please reload pH7Builder

`

**Note** In my localhost Wampp Server It works perfectly

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not a great description of the issue! By blank what do you mean, is there any errors? Did you also move the database? Did you check the error logs for any clues

Comment: "Did you also move the database?" No, database is new and empty.
"Did you check the error logs for any clues" I added code, but no errors, blank page
[code]error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);[/code]

Comment: Why not just delete the `_install` folder instead of renaming it

Comment: "Why not just delete the _install folder instead of renaming it " I delete folder and rename, same problem